# Insert qcircuit inside xymatrix environment

Tags: diagrams, xy-pic, circuits, xymatrix

I need to combine some quantum circuit as a node between arrows. Does everybody know how to put a quantum circuit as a point inside xymatrix?

Here is an example of the code

```
\[\xymatrix@C+=3cm{
  A
  \ar @{~)} @<3ex> [r]
    & 
  B 
 \Qcircuit @C=1em @R=.7em {
   & \multimeasureD{1}{\text{Bell}} &\\
   & \ghost{\text{Bell}}
 \ar @2 @<-1ex> @[l]
 }\]
```

I'm expecting to get something like this

[image: qcircuit element as a node in xymatrix]

but it turns out not working.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  Please take a moment to take our [Tour](http://tex.stackexchange.com/tour)!  You may also want to look at what makes a good Minimal Working Example ([MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can nest `\Qcircuit` in `\xymatrix`. You can use a box, though.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\usepackage{qcircuit}

\newsavebox{\cicabox}

\begin{document}

\[
\sbox\cicabox{%
  \Qcircuit @C=1em @R=.7em {
    & \multimeasureD{1}{\text{Bell}} &\\
    & \ghost{\text{Bell}}
  }%
}
\xymatrix@C+=3cm@R=0pt{
  A \ar@{~)}@<1ex>[r] &
  B
  \ar@{=>}@<1ex>[l]
  \\
  &\rlap{\hspace{-1em}\usebox{\cicabox}}
}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent! just what I need! :) Thanks a lot!